# Strategy for virtualised Windows Server Updates to reduce downtime

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, windows-update

We have a wonderful VMWare based visualized environment that has, until now, been hosting a collection of Linux based VMs. We've now added in a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM that hosts a SQL Server instance.

Does there exist a nifty strategy for applying windows updates that reduces or eliminates server downtime?

I've got as far as thinking about cloning the server, applying the update and then switching the network but by then SQL server would be out of date.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Clusters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  A lot of effort to go through to avoid a few minutes of downtime once a month, though.

Answer (score 5):

Windows server downtime for updates is inevitable.  Service downtime is avoidable, however. The key is to realize that downtime needs to be measured by service availability, not the status of individual servers.

For your SQL Server instance, your best bet is to implement some form of multi-server instancing. One technique that Microsoft allows in SQL Server 2014 is [AlwaysOn Clustering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929171.aspx) (failover clustering and availability groups).  Earlier versions had similar technologies for clustering and/or failover.

The two main strategies that are used in the generic sense are failover and load balancing. For a failover pair with one active and one standby node, if the primary node goes down, then the other one should seamlessly take over as the service provider.  For intelligent load balancing, the traffic is shared between multiple nodes and downed hosts are automatically excluded.

The cost for most of these techniques, especially for databases that need to stay current, can be high. For database clustering you generally should have enterprise-class shared storage, which can be a costly investment if you don't already have such a system in place. Also, be sure to check your licensing permissions and costs which may change once you introduce clustering or failover solutions.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that VMware vSphere does nothing to increase availability for individual servers during patching.

Comment: @mfinni I don't even understand how it could while still maintaining DB integrity.

Comment: Right - that's my point to Rob, it doesn't do anything for that. vMotion, HA, and FT can keep an OS instance up (or at least get it restarted) after a physical host failure. It doesn't prevent an OS from rebooting when you patch the kernel.